# How can I prevent my dependency from loading multiple times at the start of a .NET Core Application?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I have a .Net Core application where we are using dependency injection. All of our providers, as we call them, are registered in the Startup.cs file and are set up as services.AddTransient providers. I have a controller that injects one of the providers as a dependency, and that provider in turn injects a few other dependencies.

The problem I am having is that one of the other providers that is injected into the first one, is being called 8 times. I have placed a break point on a few lines in the constructor method for the second dependency, and I can see it's being called 8 times. I went through the dependency chain and could not find a reason for this. I also stepped through the start of the application and noticed there were a number of dependencies that were created, that had nothing to do with the provider I was starting with. Am I using dependency injection incorrectly? I just can't find an explanation as to why it would load a dependency 8 times.

This is part of my startup class, if it helps.

```
            services.AddTransient<IResourceProvider, ResourceProvider>();
            services.AddTransient<IStaticListProvider, StaticListProvider>();
            services.AddTransient<IPlanActivityLineItemProvider, PlanActivityLineItemProvider>();
            services.AddTransient<IPlanRevisionProvider, PlanRevisionProvider>();
            services.AddTransient<IProjectImportExportProvider, ProjectImportExportProvider>();
            services.AddTransient<IExpandoParserProvider, ExpandoParseProvider>();
            services.AddTransient<IProjectPlanProvider, ProjectPLanProvider>();
            services.AddTransient<IActualsImportProvider, ActualsImportProvider>();
            services.AddTransient<IReportProvider, ReportProvider>();
            services.AddTransient<IProjectWorkFlowProvider, ProjectWorkflowProvider>();
```

EDIT:
Sorry, I didn't provide enough code to help with this. Our controller takes in a dependency, we call that class a Provider. Most of our providers also inject one or more dependencies. The code below is the start of the provider class, along with the constructor method. Hopefully this explains the Provider issue. I placed a break point on one of the lines of the constructor, and as the application was starting, it stopped at this break point 8 times, which leads me to believe that it's instantiating the provider 8 times. And I can't find a reason for this. I followed the dependency chain and it's not like it's being called again in another provider. I don't see a logical explanation for it. When an application starts, is every single service instantiated?

```
        private readonly IURCSRepo _repo;
        private readonly IPlanRevisionProvider _planRevisionProvider;
        private readonly IExcelFileAndSheetValidationProvider _excelImportValidationProvider;
        private readonly IExcelExtensionsProvider _excelExtensionsProvider;
        private readonly IEmailProvider _emailProvider;
        private readonly string _rpmActuals = "Actuals";
        private TableParser<ActualHoursLineItemImportModel> _rpmLineItemTableParser;
        private List<RoleDescriptionModel> roleModels = new List<RoleDescriptionModel>();
        private List<PlanResourceModel> resources = new List<PlanResourceModel>();
        private List<ProjectPlanHeaderModel> projectPlanHeaders = new List<ProjectPlanHeaderModel>();
        private List<ChargingStrategyModel> chargingStrategies = new List<ChargingStrategyModel>();
        private List<HoursTypeModel> hoursTypes = new List<HoursTypeModel>();
        private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;

        public ActualsImportProvider(IURCSRepo uRCSRepo, IPlanRevisionProvider planRevisionProvider, IExcelFileAndSheetValidationProvider excelFileAndSheetValidationProvider, IExcelExtensionsProvider excelExtensionsProvider, IEmailProvider emailProvider, UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
        {
            _repo = uRCSRepo;
            _planRevisionProvider = planRevisionProvider;
            _excelImportValidationProvider = excelFileAndSheetValidationProvider;
            _excelExtensionsProvider = excelExtensionsProvider;
            _rpmLineItemTableParser = new TableParser<ActualHoursLineItemImportModel>(_excelExtensionsProvider);
            _emailProvider = emailProvider;
            roleModels = _repo.GetAllRoleDescriptions(true).MakeRoleDescriptions();
            resources = _repo.GetAllActiveResources().MakePlanResources();
            projectPlanHeaders = _repo.GetAllProjectPlanHeaders().MakeProjectPlanHeaderList();
            chargingStrategies = _repo.GetAllChargingStrategies().MakeChargingStrategies();
            hoursTypes = _repo.GetAllHoursTypes(true).MakeHoursTypes();
            _userManager = userManager;
        }
```

Edit 2: I tried to set the services up as AddSingleton and I got the following error. This the repo interface, and it's used on 90% of our providers:

```
InvalidOperationException: Cannot consume scoped service 'XXXXXXXSystem.Data.Entities.XXXXXXXSystemContext' from singleton 'XXXXXXXSystem.Data.Interfaces.IXXXXRepo'.
```

I am setting all of these up in the Startup.cs file, under ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services).

Based on what I have read and what some of you are saying, there seems to be a fundamental problem with how our DI container is set up. I say this because there are so many (10 or 20) providers that load up, when there are only 2 required for the index page. And, as I've said, some are loading multiple times. From what I understand, it should only load what is needed. We are using the Microsoft DI container. Should I be using something like AutoFac instead?

Edit 3: I started going through the break points and looking at the call stack, like someone suggested. We use service filters extensively on our controllers, in order to intercept the request to provide information that's common. We have a base filter, and then some other filters that are more specific to a particular controller. So, the specific filter calls the base filter to get some basic information. I discovered that one of our filters was calling a provider, and that provider called a number of others that have nothing to do with the initial page of the application.

I think this may be boiling down to some poor architecture, in that we have to many providers that are referencing too many others. Following the dependency chain gets confusing, once I looked at the filters.

Does this sound about right?

Comment: You described the relationships between some of these classes, but you haven't actually shown it. That would make the situation a lot more understandable. Please review [mcve] so you get a better idea of what we need in order to help you. And what you mean by the "provider is being called 8 times"? Do you mean 8 different instances of a provider are created? Or that one provider is created and some method on it is called 8 times? What dependencies are you seeing that have nothing to do with the provider?

Comment: Please elaborate with some minimally reproducible code. It's hard to say without knowing what each of these classes require in their constructors. You may be looking for `services.AddSingleton` if you want to force any of these to be registered as singletons

Comment: When your code hits the breakpoint, have a look at the CallStack window.  It may show you where the dependency tree is originating from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transient objects are always different; a new instance is provided to every controller and every service (your case I presume).

Scoped objects are the same within a request, but different across different requests.

Singleton objects are the same for every object and every request.

Comment: I've read that in my own search for an answer to this. Are the services for every controller instantiated when the application starts, even though the first page in the application only uses one controller?

Comment: The answer to that is No.  When a request comes in the routing system will use the URI to determine the relevant controller and instantiate that controller by requesting it from the DI container.  The DI container will then try to resolve all constructor parameters for that controller.  Each constructor parameter (dependency) will in turn have dependencies that need resolving for the original controller to be instantiated and so on until all dependencies are satisfied.  If the same dependency is required in multiple places and is registered as transient then you'll see multiple instantiations.

Answer (score -1):

You could register your services as Singletons so they only get instantiated once:

```
services.AddSingleton<ISomeService, SomeService>();
```